# removeClass Error. <Nodelist> has no method removeClass

Tags: jquery, class, removeclass

Object # has no method 'removeClass' I always get this error.

```
defaultcolor = document.getElementsByClassName('default');
defaultcolor.removeClass("default");`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removeClass is a jQuery Method, if you don't have jQuery in your webpage, it will not work because you get an html object, not a jQuery object.

If you already have included jQuery, get the element like this:

```
 $('.default').removeClass('default');
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `defaultcolor` variable contains a standard DOM Element which has no `removeClass` method. You need to select the element using jQuery to be able to use jQuery's methods on it. Try this:

```
$('.default').removeClass('default');
```